# PGP - Verify signed key from a signed file received

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

Can you please help me with the following issue:

I have a **file.pgp** and I want verify the userID/Key that signed it, before decrypt the file.

Now I runs:

1. Verify the file `pgp --verify "C:\Folder\file.pgp"`:

> C:\Folder\file.pgp:verify (3042:suggested output file name file.txt)
>
> C:\Folder\file.pgp:verify (3177:message signed by key ID 0xFRF5234B)
>
> C:\Folder\file.pgp:verify (3038:signing key 0xFRF5234B UserPGP)
>
> C:\Folder\file.pgp:verify (3040:signature created 2017-12-05T14:55:35+01:00)
>
> C:\Folder\file.pgp:verify (3170:signature hash SHA-256)
>
> C:\Folder\file.pgp:verify (3035:good signature) C:\Folder\file.pgp:verify
>
> (0:verify complete)

2. parse the OUTPUT and check if the signed by key ID is: 0xFRF5234B
3. If key ID is 0xFRF5234B, decrypt the file:

`pgp --decrypt "C:\Folder\file.pgp" --output "C:\Folder\file.xml" --overwrite remove`

**Question:** Is it possible verify the signed UserID/key without parsing the output? Is there, for example, a script as:

`pgp verify --signer 0xFRF5234B file.pgp`

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).